# how to debug web project using tomcat using command prompt

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat8

I am trying to run my project in local host using tomcat and starting it using cmd, steps below:

in the tomcat\bin folder, running startup.bat. 
I am not running thru eclipse as tomcat8 is starting up but when i hit the localhost, it is not working. 
so my question is how can I debug the code while I am starting tomcat thru cmd?

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you're looking for more help, please provide some indication that you have done some research. Have you tried **[this](http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html)**?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using startup.bat, use this command:

```
catalina jpda start
```

Then, in eclipse, set up a up a Remote Java Application debug configuration: Connection Type: Standard (Socket Attach), host: localhost, port: 8000

To debug, open Run->Debug Configurations..., select your remote configuration, and click Debug. You can set breakpoints in your code and debug.